# Publishing a .NET 6 project with C# 10 implicit usings via Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, msdeploy, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

When publishing an ASP.NET Core 6 web application with C# 10's `<ImplicitUsings />` enabled to an Azure App Service from a Visual Studio 2022 publishing profile, the publishing build fails due to missing `using` statements.

### Background

C# 10 introduces the new [implicit usings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/#implicit-usings) feature, where certain `using` directives are treated as [*global* `using` directives](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/#global-using-directives) based on the SDK. This can be enabled with the following `csproj` configuration:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works exactly as expected with a local build. E.g., when targeting the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK, I'm able to remove `using` directives for `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`, &c.

### Publishing Error

When publishing to an Azure App Service from a Visual Studio 2022 publishing profile, however, the build output shows errors such as the following:

```
C:\Code\MyWebApp\MyClass.cs(41,25): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IEnumerable<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This can be seen below as part of an expanded context:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: MyWebApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>Done building project "MyWebApp.csproj".
2>------ Publish started: Project: MyWebApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /platform:x64 /errorreport:prompt /warn:6 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NET;NET6_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NET6_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference: /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\MyWebApp.dll /refout:obj\Release\net6.0\win-x64\ref\MyWebApp.dll /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:10.0 /analyzerconfig:… /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\analyzers\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Analyzers.dll" /additionalfile:Areas\MyArea\Index.cshtml … /warnaserror+:NU1605
C:\Code\MyWebApp\MyClass.cs(41,25): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IEnumerable<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I assume this has something to do with the `csc.exe` command generated by the publishing profile.

### Publishing Profile

Unfortunately, it's not immediately obvious to me how to remedy this within my `pubxml` file, which is pretty straight-forward:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/77e95f68-ed69-4bfe-9bbe-0b4d3910722e/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MyWebApp</ResourceId>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>77e95f68-ed69-4bfe-9bbe-0b4d3910722e</ProjectGuid>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>mywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net:443</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>MyWebApp</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>$MyWebApp</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <_DestinationType>AzureWebSite</_DestinationType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <InstallAspNetCoreSiteExtension>False</InstallAspNetCoreSiteExtension>
    <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

(Note: `ResourceId`, `ProjectGuid`, &c. have been anonymized and don't refer to an actual property.)

### Question

Acknowledging this is a new feature in a new version of Visual Studio, this could be a bug. That said, are there any `pubxml` properties that are needed to enable the `<ImplicitUsing />` feature? Or is there something else that's needed to enable this feature with Visual Studio publishing profiles?

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is that the `csc.exe` isn't aware of the `csproj` file itself, and thus needs to have some type of flag set to enable implicit usings. So the next steps will be to a) determine what that flag is on `csc.exe`, and b) how to set that flag via the `pubxml`. I'll investigate both of these tomorrow unless the community beats me to it by posting a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it appears that this was a false alarm. I apparently neglected to finish rebooting my workstation after installing the release version of Visual Studio 2022. After restarting, I am now able to publish with full support for implicit usings. Whoops.

That said, this *does* provide a good opportunity to offer some insight into what I discovered after the fact, which may help future readers with similar types of issues—and certainly helped me better understand the integration between the various command-line tools.

#### Command-Line Arguments

Notably, there doesn't appear to be any command-line *parameters* for handling implicit usings built into any of the following tools:

- .NET 6.0 SDK (`dotnet.exe`)
- Visual C# compiler (`csc.exe`)
- Microsoft Build Engine (`msbuild.exe`)

#### Microsoft Build Support

Instead, this is handled via the Microsoft Build Engine (`msbuild.exe`) when working off of a C# project file (`*.csproj`), at which point it generates the following intermediate file at:

```
/{BaseIntermediateOutputPath}/{Configuration}/net6.0/{MyWebApp}.GlobalUsings.g.cs
```

e.g., by default:

```
/obj/Release/net6.0/MyWebApp.GlobalUsings.g.cs
```

This file contains global `using` directives that are specific to the configured SDK:

```cs
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
global using global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
…
```

In turn, this file is appended to the underlying call to the C# Compiler (`csc.exe`).

> ***Note:*** The .NET 6.0 SDK—i.e., `dotnet.exe`—provides a wrapper around `msbuild.exe` as part of either the `build` or `publish` commands, and thus offers the same functionality. Further, by default, the .NET SDK will persist the intermediate files in the `/obj` folder, whereas `msbuild.exe` immediately deletes them.

#### C# 10 Support

Given this, the implicit usings feature isn’t actually part of C# 10 *per se*—[despite being advertised as such](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/#implicit-usings)—but is rather a bit of tooling built into the Microsoft Build Engine (`msbuild.exe`). The C# 10 compiler (`csc.exe`) *does* supports [global `using` directives](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/#global-using-directives), but has no awareness of *implicit* usings.

Ultimately, this isn't *too* surprising, as the C# compiler (`csc.exe`) isn't actually aware of C# project files (`*.csproj`) themselves—those are an artifact of the Microsoft Build Engine, with pass-through support via the .NET SDK.

#### Conclusion

It's unclear why local builds worked successfully with this prior to a full reboot, while calls using Visual Studio 2022's publishing profiles failed. I assume this has something to do with how Visual Studio assembles the arguments for the C# Compiler (`csc.exe`) as part of the publishing process. Regardless, it's an easy solution to just reboot the workstation after installation. Otherwise, this post will hopefully help demystify the overall process.

Comment: Small nit: `dotnet.exe` _does not_ provide a wrapper around `msbuild.exe`. `msbuild.exe` is the .NET Framework based version of MSBuild that ships with Visual Studio. `dotnet.exe` includes a .NET Core based version of MSBuild (as a dll, not an executable). The two versions of MSBuild do not have complete feature parity.